# Populate Dropdown List with DB table item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a table with about 3 items. I wish to populate the `Dropdown List` using that table. But i have a condition that i want to show only 2 items in the Dropdown List. How can it be done?

Comment: what is the condition ? which all two items you want to show ? top 2 ?

Comment: not top 2. I have to use multiple drop down against same table but in some view all the table items are not necessary.

Comment: check Darin's answer. You may need to change your Where clause to get the 2 items based on your criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then take the first 2 items (obviously if your requirements is to take some other 2 items based on some condition you could chain with the `.Where()` extension method in order to filter first before calling `.Take()`):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Items = db.Items.Take(2).ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.Id,
        Text = x.SomeText
    });
    return View(model);
}
```

The view is standard stuff, simply call to the DropDownListFor helper:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemId, Model.Items)
```

Comment: I got a problem. The view is strongly typed with another model. How do i do it now?

Comment: You simply add the 2 properties that I have shown (`SelectedItemId` and `Items`) to your view model then. And now if you tell me that this view model is something that you cannot modify because it is an autogenerated EF class, I tell you that it is a very bad practice to pass domain models to your views and you should use view models. So in this case you define a wrapping view model that might encapsulate your domain model as a property in addition to the 2 properties I have shown in my answer.